# Log to separate files from class instances that run in different processes

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

### Problem

In a main process, I instantiate multiple class instances that run a method in parallel and should log to their own log file. Before and after they have finished their work, some events from the main process should be logged to yet another file.

Since there is no parallel access to the same file at any time during program execution, I don't use a queue to serialize the logging events. I just use a base logger and for each module a separate logger that inherits from the base logger.

My problem now is that the class instances that execute their methods in parallel use functions from a utils module. The logger in this utils module should log to the file of the class instance that it is used by, which it only can do if it knows the correct name of the logger as far as I know.

---

### Example code

I reduced the real code to a minimal working example to help better understand my problem. In the main module I instantiate a base logger called 'Main' that only has a `StreamHandler` and from which every other logger in the application inherits

```
# Content of main.py

import logging
import multiprocessing
import time

from worker import Worker
from container import Container

logger = logging.getLogger('Main')

def setup_base_logger():
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)-14s - %(levelname)8s - %(message)s')
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    setup_base_logger()
    logger.warning('Starting the main program')
    container = Container([Worker(name='Worker_Nr.%d' % i) for i in range(4)])
    container.run()
```

The `Container` class is defined in container.py and just holds a list of `Worker` instances:

```
# Content of container.py

import logging
import multiprocessing

logger = logging.getLogger('Main.container')

def run_worker(worker):
    worker.run()

class Container:
    def __init__(self, workers):
        self.workers = workers

    def run(self):
        logger.warning('The workers begin to run ...')
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4, maxtasksperchild=1)
        pool.map(run_worker, self.workers)
        logger.warning('Workers finished running.')
```

Its task is to execute the `run()` method of the workers in parallel. I use a `multiprocessing.Pool` because I need to restrict the number of processors used. The `Worker` class is defined in the module worker.py:

```
# Content of worker.py

import logging
import os
import time

import util

def configure_logger(name, logfile):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)-14s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode='w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.run_time = 2
        logger_name = 'Main.worker.' + name
        configure_logger(name=logger_name, logfile=self.name + '.log')
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        if 'logger' in d:
            d['logger'] = d['logger'].name
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        if 'logger' in d:
            d['logger'] = logging.getLogger(d['logger'])
        self.__dict__.update(d)

    def run(self):
        self.logger.warning('{0} is running for {1} seconds with process id {2}'.format(self.name, self.run_time, os.getpid()))
        time.sleep(self.run_time)
        util.print_something(os.getpid())
        self.logger.warning('{} woke up!'.format(self.name))
```

I figured that `Worker` needs a logger instance as an attribute if there should be one log file for every instance of `Worker`. The utils module looks like this:

```
# Content of util.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('Main.util')

def print_something(s):
    print(s)
    logger.warning('%s was just printed', s)
```

Executing main.py gives the following output:

```
2017-05-03 11:08:05,738 - Main           -  WARNING - Starting the main program
2017-05-03 11:08:05,740 - Main.container -  WARNING - The workers begin to run ...
Worker_Nr.0 is running for 2 seconds with process id 5532
Worker_Nr.1 is running for 2 seconds with process id 17908
Worker_Nr.2 is running for 2 seconds with process id 19796
Worker_Nr.3 is running for 2 seconds with process id 10804
5532
5532 was just printed
Worker_Nr.0 woke up!
17908
19796
17908 was just printed
19796 was just printed
Worker_Nr.1 woke up!
Worker_Nr.2 woke up!
10804
10804 was just printed
Worker_Nr.3 woke up!
2017-05-03 11:08:07,941 - Main.container -  WARNING - Workers finished running.
```

As you can see, the format is missing for the log records created by the `Worker` instances. Also, the log files that were created don't have any content. How is that possible if a add the formatted handler with `configure_logger()` in `Worker.__init__`?

---

*What I have tried*

- Pass the logger name to every function in the utils module. This works but seems overcomplicated as there are a lot of functions in util.py and more modules being used in this manner
- Similar questions concerning logging in multiprocessing applications usually want to log to the same file from different processes, I would like a separate log file for each process

### Question

1. How is it possible for log records created in the utils module (and possibly other modules) to go to the correct log file?
2. Everything that is being logged from the `Worker` instance is emitted to stdout without a format and nothing is written to the log files (but they are created). Why?

I'm using Python 3.5.1 on Windows 7 64 bit.

If you think that it is much easier to work with a `Queue` and a logging thread in the main process, that would totally be acceptable. My only concern is the order of the logs. I guess I could sort them afterwards though, as suggested in a few other posts.

I'm at my wits' end and any help or a hint in the right direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat

```
configure_logger(name=logger_name, logfile=self.name + '.log')
```

for every process

```
def run(self):
    configure_logger(name=logger_name, logfile=self.name + '.log')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With this minimal example, I was able to reproduce the original error that prompted you to modify your `Worker` class so that it could be pickled:

```
import logging
import multiprocessing
import time

def configure_logger(name, logfile):
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)-14s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile, mode='w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.name = "worker%d" % number
        self.log_file = "%s.log" % self.name
        configure_logger(self.name, self.log_file)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info("%s is running...", self.name)
        time.sleep(1.0)
        self.logger.info("%s is exiting...", self.name)

def run_worker(worker):
    worker.run()

N = 4
workers = [Worker(n) for n in range(N)]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=N, maxtasksperchild=1)
pool.map(run_worker, workers)
```

This is the exception traceback from running this program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom.py", line 31, in <module>
    pool.map(run_worker, workers)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
```

The solution is not to change how the `Worker` class is pickled, but to call `logging.getLogger` in the `run` method:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.name = "worker%d" % number
        self.log_file = "%s.log" % self.name
        configure_logger(self.name, self.log_file)

    def run(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        self.logger.info("%s is running...", self.name)
        time.sleep(1.0)
        self.logger.info("%s is exiting...", self.name)
```

With this change, the program runs, and the expected log files are generated.

Comment: Thank you for proposing a solution! Though I don't see a difference between your solution and the first point of my _What I have tried_. Every function that retrieves a logger from `get_file_logger` would need the logger name and file as an argument, or did I get something wrong?

Comment: I figured out why you were changing the pickling behavior of the `Worker` class and the error it generated. I updated the solution with the explanation of the real problem and the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for further looking into my problem and sorry for responding so late! In the meantime I decided to log to the same file from every process. I could not find a way for the utils module functions to log to the correct file without passing that information to the functions. Now I still can snip and sort the file afterwards with %(processName)s in the formatter. Thanks again for helping me!